# HAProxy error detected while parsing switching rule : no such ACL : '{hdr(host)'

Tags: ssl, haproxy

Working on configuring HAProxy with SSL for our lower environment. Currently, the LB is working for non-ssl but we are converting to use SSL. We have multiple sites in QA and for non-ssl I am using ACL's and its working fine.

For some reason when I restart the service I receive the following error:

Dec  9 10:56:11 haproxy haproxy: [ALERT] 343/105611 (52875) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:27] : error detected while parsing switching rule : no such ACL : '{hdr(host)'.

Here is my current SSL Config:

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
   log global
   mode http
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   option dontlognull
   option forwardfor
   option http-server-close
   stats enable
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 50000
   timeout server 50000


frontend qa_b2b_https_front
   mode http
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs.d/
   use_backend qa_b2b_http_back if {hdr(host) -i qawebsecure.oursite.com}

backend qa_b2b_http_back
   server qab2b 10.5.140.176:80 check
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define anonymous ACLs, you have to add a space before and after the opening and closing brace.

To quote [the documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#7.2) on this topic:

> It is also possible to form rules using "anonymous ACLs". Those are unnamed ACL
> expressions that are built on the fly without needing to be declared. They must
> be enclosed between braces, with a space before and after each brace (because
> the braces must be seen as independent words).

As such, your `use_backend` rule should look like this instead:

```
use_backend qa_b2b_http_back if { hdr(host) -i qawebsecure.oursite.com }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, and receive another error: Dec  9 11:14:28 haproxy haproxy: [ALERT] 343/111428 (53034) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

Comment: I ran the the config check program and it says: [ALERT] 343/113230 (53170) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:26] : 'bind *:443' unknown keyword 'ssl' - I am on v1.8.20 so I am sure SSL is supported.

Comment: This is a different problem. It might be caused by you omitting SSL support when compiling your HAProxy binary. You may need to specify `USE_OPENSSL=1` when compiling haproxy. Please refer to the comments in the `Makefile`.

Comment: I agree - I just figured this out after checking the version and not seeing the SSL support. Is there a way to recompile after its already been installed/configured? Or should I just re-do the entire installation?

Comment: That depends on how you installed HAProxy. But given that HAProxy consists only of a single executable, it should be rather simple to just replace that.

Comment: (Also if you found my answer useful, you may [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and possibly vote on it.)

Comment: I was able to recompile my install of haproxy and SSL is now supported. I was able to get passed any config issues but unfortunately, the site times out. I appreciate the assistance and will mark it as an answer.